# How to automatically update a page without refreshing in django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am creating a website using Django on the stock market. I am fetching the live stock market data from an API. I want to update the live price of a stock every 5 seconds (which is given by the API). How can I do this without refreshing the page? I found that Ajax is very helpful for this but I am not being able to implement this properly. Thus, can someone please give an example of the code which is required in the Html page to update the values using Ajax. I was thinking of using a separate URL that could send the data in a JSON format. Please help me out if possible.

Comment: What did you try with ajax and what did not work? Add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **setInterval** or **setTimeout**:

Using ES5

```js
var $price = $('#price');

var interval = setInterval(function() {
   fetch('api').then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
   }).then(function(json) {
      $price.html(json.price);
   });
}, 1000);
```

using more modern JavaScript:

```js
const $price = $('#price');

var interval = setInterval(async function() {
   const res = await fetch('api');
   const json = await res.json();
   $price.html(json.price);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you better use django channels
You will need to use asynchronous django views and I think this is the most accurate way to do your job